# How do you install the PostgreSQL tablefunc extension?

Tags: postgresql, table-functions, postgresql-extensions

I am not able to run the following command in my PostgreSQL server:

`CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;`

When I run this command, I get the following error message:

`ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/pgsql/share/extension/tablefunc.control": No such file or directory`

I could not find any resources online which explain how to install this file/directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**CREATE** EXTENSION **IF NOT EXISTS** tablefunc;

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You have to install the "contrib" installation package.

On a Redhat based distribution, that is something like

```sh
sudo dnf install -y postgresql13-server
```